# why @ before functions

Tags: php

What does adding @ before a function do? I've seen this in some scripts

example:

```
$connect = @mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
 instead of
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It suppresses any errors that might happen inside the function. [Documentation here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).

All things considered, this is not recommended as it can lead to some sneaky bugs.

Comment: Well I don't have a problem with someone improving a post of mine but to completely change the wording of it within minutes of me posting it is in poor taste at best...

Comment: It's also slow. Don't use it; there is almost always another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

this is the **Error Control Operator**, from php documentation:

> PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (`@`). When prepended to an expression in PHP, **any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored**.
>
> If you have set a custom error handler function with `set_error_handler()` then it will still get called, but this custom error handler can (and should) call `error_reporting()` which will return 0 when the call that triggered the error was preceded by an `@`.
>
> If the track_errors feature is enabled, any error message generated by the expression will be saved in the variable `$php_errormsg`. This variable will be overwritten on each error, so check early if you want to use it.